# Ssh audio redirection

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, audio

I have DVB-T USB dongle plugged into my Linux server (GUI-less). It works correctly, but I want to stream TV programs from server to my PC. For this I use Kaffeine that way:

```
ssh -X -p 666 -i /home/maciek/.ssh/id_rsa media@media env LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8 /usr/bin/kaffeine
```

As You can see, ssh works on port 666 and starts kaffeine on server but display results on my PC. Nice but the problem is audio redirection. Is any way to redirect audio together with video and keyboard/mouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X11 has two neat aspects: it's a de facto standard for display on Linux, and it's network-transparent. There is unfortunately no such thing for sound. There are [sound servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_server) which do exactly what you want; unlike X which works out of the box, sound servers tend to require a little setup.

[JACK](http://jackit.sourceforge.net/) and [Pulseaudio](http://pulseaudio.org/) are the two choices that I recommend investigating. Pulseaudio is the default sound system on Ubuntu, which gives it an edge in terms of using on Ubuntu and in terms of tutorials available. JACK prides itself on its low latency, which is important when watching a movie.

You'll need to do three things:

- Set up Kaffeine for JACK or Pulseaudio output, and indicate a port (say 5551).
- On your desktop computer, set up the sound server to listen on a port (say 5552 — it can be the same as in your soundless server or not). The Arch wiki has howtos for [JACK](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK) and [Pulseaudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network). [This Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers) also has hints about PA. There is a [guide for JACK2](http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/NetJack2) on the JACK site.
- Set up SSH to forward connections from the server to the client: `-R 5551:localhost:5552`

Comment: OK. But can I rum pulseaudio and/or JACK on GUI-less server?

Comment: @user180586 Yes, sure. Why on earth wouldn't it be possible? There's no connection between having a local GUI and being able to run software.

Comment: OK. THX. I wull try!